# how to display number when i click on button !it repeats multiple !when i pressed many times like pressing number button in id

Tags: react-native

I am developing code for number pad on-screen! When I click the button for example '7' for multiple times It will display multiple times.

I gave static value in update state method and called through button it's showing only one time

```
this.state={
    id:''
}

ChangeTextFunction=()=>{
    this.setState({                
        id:'7'         
    })
}
```

Comment: use an array instead of the object, and on every click simply add new value in the array.

Comment: can you please tell me small code !thank you for rply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are very unclear about the question. what i derive is you are asking for like if a guy presses 789 then it should come as 789 or 7 then below that 8 then below that 9.

If its the first , then on any number click it should call this

```
let newId = `${this.state.id}${num}`
    this.setState({
       id: newId 
    });
  }
```

or if you want one after another

```
let newId = `${this.state.id}
             ${num}`
    this.setState({
       id: newId 
    });
  }
```

and every time you have to pass the num which you type in the function

Comment: awesome bro!its working, how to clear the last element which I clicked on the clear button! will anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple solution. When you change the current state, add the content you want to add.

**Usage**

[Click this link](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/add-state-value) to experience this code.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state={
       id:''
    }
  }

  ChangeTextFunction= () => {
    this.setState({
       id: this.state.id + '7' 
    });
  }

  clearId = () =>{
     this.setState({
        id:''
     })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          {this.state.id}
        </Text>
        <Button title="add id" onPress={this.ChangeTextFunction} />
        <Button title="clear id" onPress={this.clearId} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Tq so much!I'm new to react-native!one more question when I click clear how it deletes,Tq for previous question

Comment: @prasadangara I edited it by adding a method of deletion.

Comment: What's not working? It is natural to look like text.

Comment: sorry, it's working!when I click the clear button on the screen how to remove the last element in. react-native

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the new value with existing value of state:

```
ChangeTextFunction=(value)=>{
let updatedValue = this.state.id + value
this.setState({
   id:updatedValue
})
```

To clear text, use blow function:

```
clearText = () =>{
    this.setState({
       id:''
    })
}
```

Comment: the above code you have sent is for when we click clear.it removes right? or for the first question, you suggested?

Comment: sorry for that!the above code is not working! the task is number pad on the screen, when we click any button like 7,8,9!it should be below . in text! please help me, anyone! I have to close the task within 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
this.state = {
    ids: []
}

ChangeTextFunction = (id) => {
    const { ids } = this.state;
    ids.push(id);
    this.setState({ ids });
};
```

And then map `this.state.ids` in your component:

```
return (
    <div>
        {this.state.ids.map((id) => {
            <span key={id}>{id}</span>
        })}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: sorry for that!the above code is not working! the task is number pad on the screen, when we click any button like 7,8,9!it should be below . in text! please help me, anyone! I have to close the task within 1 hour